# serial port send/receive wrong character

Tags: serial-port

I want to set up a serial link between my old zaurus and my pc, here is the pinout for the zaurus :
  http://www.geocities.jp/tedmiy/ppphsl.html

I used the ttl-to-usb converter to connect the pin 3,4,15 of the zaurus, but when I try to send data with minicom to the other side, I always got the wrong character(same with zaurus to pc or pc to zaurus), below is the table(left colcum is the key I pressed, right column is the character I get, N/A means scrambled code)

- a -> O
- b -> '
- c -> N
- d -> N/A
- e -> M
- f -> &
- g -> L
- h -> tab
- i -> K
- j -> %
- k -> J
- l -> N/A
- m -> I
- n -> %
- o -> H
- p -> N/A
- q -> G
- r -> #
- s -> F
- t -> N/A
- u -> E
- v -> "
- w -> D
- x -> N/A
- y -> C
- z -> !

both sides are using the same setup, I have no  idea whats wrong...

Comment: It is an electrical problem.  When the device sends a 1 you get a 0.  And when it sends 0 then you get 1.  Difficult to see the pattern because the bit inversion also prevents the start bit from getting detected correctly.  Use electronics.stackexchange.com to ask a question about your hardware setup.

Comment: it turns out that the io pins from zaurus are inverted.....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stackoverflow is not about blue-white and white-blue wire pairs (though we care)

Answer (score 0):

- Check your parity and control flow settings.
- Try to set different charset for minicom.
- It's a silly guess, but did you try to reboot usb-serial converter and your PC? I faced similar issue with my ARM system-on-module, connected to serial port.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are connecting a serial cable straight to a USB breakout cable.  You need a USB to serial circuit to make this work.